# How to grant access to files only to token holders?

Tags: tokens

I’m creating a dApp that allows people to buy tokens (ERC1155) that grants them access to certain files. Different tokens will give access to different files. Tokens of the similar type will give access to the same file and that file only. I don’t want these files or the urls to download them to be accessible to non-token holders.

The plan is to store these files in a decentralised system, currently looking into private IPFS networks, Peergos, etc.

Without building a centralised service with my backend and private db to serve the urls to these files, is there a way to either generate the url from the signature of a token-holder or present that url when the token-holder connects their wallet to the dApp?

If this is not the best approach, what would be a better way to implement this?